# How to import informal XML to SQL DB 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have informal XML file And want to import into MS SQL, How to do ?

```
    <ROOT>
      <XDOC BEGIN="1">
       <SECTION1 SEGMENT="1">
        <KUNNR>RHX2</KUNNR>
        <KTOKD>120</KTOKD>
        <NAME1>REF.RHX2</NAME1>
        <NAME2>NAME2</NAME2>
        <CITYC>2</CITYC>
        <SECTION2 SEGMENT="1">
           <VKORG>RH02</VKORG>
           <VTWEG>R5</VTWEG>
        </SECTION2>
        <SECTION3 SEGMENT="1">
           <VTWE7>HELLO</VTWE7>
        </SECTION3>
       </SECTION1>
</ROOT>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Depends on how you want the data persisted in SQL Server. You can store the entire XML in a blob or you can shred it in various ways.

Comment: Yes I want to import to table in sql and I can't query in xml format. I search any solution in google but It is formal xml file. I can slove my problem via programming but xml file too much and large size.I concern about CPU performace.

Comment: Why can't you query the XML? Is it because it is invalid?

Comment: Yes, It is informal xml.

Comment: Never heard that expression do describe *invalid* XML before. If the XML is invalid you should not try to fix it. It is the responsibility the source system to produce valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. Maximum you can import as a string nvarchar(max) and you need to process again. doesn't change anything.

My opinion if there is any chance to convert formal format from informal format without spending too much effort use regular expression to formal format xml from your informal xml file(s). Afterthat you can easily import proper xml file(s) to your database

Comment: Yes but I can't control xml format becasue my vendor export data from SAP to my system.